# Script to multiple number fields

Tags: shell-script

I have a large file with loads of different text. I want to use a script that will go through the whole file and multiple the number by a predetermined amount, in this example 2 in the EXP="XYZ" number field. However it must only do this if VIEW_RANGE, COOLEYE and TAMEBLE are before it. The whole file is a whole one liner too.

Example

```
TAMEBLE="0" COOLEYE="20" VIEW_RANGE="9" EXP="12000"
TAMEBLE="0" COOLEYE="5" VIEW_RANGE="12" EXP="1000"
```

Should end up looking like

```
TAMEBLE="0" COOLEYE="20" VIEW_RANGE="9" EXP="24000"
TAMEBLE="0" COOLEYE="5" VIEW_RANGE="12" EXP="2000"
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Given that the sample input has two lines, what does this sentence mean? _"The whole file is a whole one liner too."_

Comment: Why did the first EXP value double but not the second?  Both lines appear to match your requirement that  EXP be preceded by _"VIEW_RANGE, COOLEYE and TAMEBLE"_.

Comment: Sorry John that's a mistake. It should have. The file just is all in one line rather than in my example but there is other stuff in between.

Comment: The sample input has values enclosed in double-quotes.  Will the values inside the double-quotes ever contain spaces?  Do `TAMEBLE`, `COOLEYE`, and  `VIEW_RANGE` always occur in the same order before `EXP`?

Comment: No they are all like the example. Only numbers in the quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider this test file:

```
$ cat file
TAMEBLE="0" COOLEYE="20" VIEW_RANGE="9" EXP="12000" other stuff EXP="2" TAMEBLE="0" COOLEYE="5" VIEW_RANGE="12" EXP="1000"
```

To double the EXP values but only if preceded by TAMEBLE, COOLEYE, and VIEW_RANGE:

```
$ awk -F'[="]+' '$1=="TAMEBLE" {a[NR]=1} $1=="COOLEYE"{b[NR]=1} $1=="VIEW_RANGE" {c[NR]=1} $1=="EXP" && a[NR-3] && b[NR-2] && c[NR-1] {$0= $1 "=\"" (2*$2) "\""} END{printf"\n"} 1' RS=' ' ORS=' ' file
TAMEBLE="0" COOLEYE="20" VIEW_RANGE="9" EXP="24000" other stuff EXP="2" TAMEBLE="0" COOLEYE="5" VIEW_RANGE="12" EXP="2000"
```

Or, if you prefer code spread out over multiple lines:

```
awk -F'[="]+' '
    $1=="TAMEBLE" {
        a[NR]=1
    }

    $1=="COOLEYE"{
        b[NR]=1
    } 

    $1=="VIEW_RANGE" {
        c[NR]=1
    } 

    $1=="EXP" && a[NR-3] && b[NR-2] && c[NR-1] {
        $0= $1 "=\"" (2*$2) "\""
    } 

    END{printf"\n"}

    1
    ' RS=' ' ORS=' ' file
```

#### How it works

- `-F'[="]+'`

  This sets the field separator to any combination of `=` or `"`.
- `$1=="TAMEBLE" {a[NR]=1}`

  If the first field of this record is TAMEBLE, then set `a[NR]` to true where `NR` is the record number.
- `$1=="COOLEYE"{b[NR]=1}`

  Likewise, if the first field of this record is COOLEYE, then set `b[NR]` to true.
- `$1=="VIEW_RANGE" {c[NR]=1}`

  Likewise, if the first field of this record is VIEW_RANGE, then set c[NR]` to true.
- `$1=="EXP" && a[NR-3] && b[NR-2] && c[NR-1] {$0= $1 "=\"" (2*$2) "\""}`

  If this record has a first field of `EXP` and the first fields of the previous records are in the required order, then double the value of `EXP`.
- `END{printf"\n"}`

  After we have finished reading the file, print one newline to properly end the line.
- `1`

  This awk's cryptic shorthand for print-the-line.
- `RS=' ' ORS=' '`

  This tells awk to treat a blank as the record separator on input and on output.